# how can I print multiple lines into one csv cell from php ?

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I exporting an records into CSV from PHP code, but I want some multiple records into a same column see below

[image]

But when use below code that gives the below results

```
foreach($rows12 as $key => $value) {

    $row['_my_marks'] .= $value['marks']."\t\n";                    
}
```

Result:

[image]

I use "\t\n" to insert into new row but it won't work. So can you please advise how i can achieve this.

Comment: You have to duplicate your row and add `Vick` and `A` again.

Comment: This is just an example I want multiple records into a same column. Please see 1 screen shot. And I want to achieve this using PHP code.

Comment: Screenshot 1 is the desired result, correct? Then you have to loop through all the `Marks` and leave `Name` and `STD` empty. Using `\t\n\r` is not going to work in order to create new physical row (only visually, sort of)

Comment: Yes... Can you please let me know the PHP code for this..

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation isn't going to work, as this is a CSV you will need to go to a new line, add two empty commas (assuming `,` is the delimiter) and then the following mark.

Comment: Do you mean to add comma instead of "\t\n" like this in php code $row['_my_marks'] .= $value['marks'].",";

Comment: More like `$row['_my_marks'] .= $value['marks']."\n,,"` but you would have to omit the ending part in the final mark (with an `if` check).

Comment: This is not working..It's giving me the result like this 10\n,,20\n,,30\n,,40\n,,

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will work

```
"\n"
```

You may follow the link [printing a new line in a csv file cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447442/printing-a-new-line-in-a-csv-file-cell)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$classreport = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Vick',
        'std' => 'A',
        'marks' => array(10, 20, 30, 40)
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Josh',
        'std' => 'B',
        'marks' => array(20, 40)
    ),
);

$csv = 'name, std, mark'."\r\n";
foreach($classreport as $student) {
    $markrows = 0;
    foreach ($student['marks'] as $marks) {
        if ($markrows == 0) {
            $csv .= sprintf('%s, %s, %d', $student['name'], $student['std'], $marks)."\r\n";
        } else {
            $csv .= sprintf(', , %d', $marks)."\r\n";
            $markrows++;
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Edit: Actually, I just realized it's easier to just add these things to arrays and then use the `csv` functions from PHP. Just consider this as pseudo-code to help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode(PHP_EOL, $array)` if you want to add content over multiple lines in a single cell.